# launch cmd.exe with color by default

Tags: windows-10, conemu

The color highlight works fine if I launch the ConEmu by double clicking the desktop shortcut. But it doesn't work with `win+r -> cmd`.

Is it possible to make the color highlight work with the latter way?

[image]

Comment: Does the working desktop shortcut provide command line arguments to "cmd", or is the configuration stored in a file? Maybe "cmd" works only if it is started from a specific directory (second line in desktop shortcut properties). Maybe it works if you move the "cmd" config file to C:\Windows\system32 or to your user folder (C:\Users\%username%).
This "cmd" is not a stock Microsoft version.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. This belongs on a site like [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: @Johannes, the desktop shortcut doesn't have any arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just take a look at [Settings/Startup](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsStartup.html) you'll see what was set in your settings to start on ConEmu startup.

[image: ConEmu settings/startup]

Of course, if you run **different** command (`cmd.exe` without arguments) you'll get "bare" command line without nicies.

So, if you want to run shell from <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, why not to run `ConEmu64` instead of `cmd`??

Answer (score 0):

CodeEmu can work with registry or config file.

https://conemu.github.io/en/Settings.html

Check your desktop shortcut to see is there's a command line parameter like /config

Comment: In the shortcut propert, there's only `Target: f:\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe`, no any argument. I spent two hours trying these settings while doing google, still cannot make it work...